# Fppf or étale extension of group algebraic spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, algebraic-spaces

Let $S$ be a scheme and let
$$0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$$
be an exact sequence of abelian sheaves on $(\mathrm{Sch}/S)_\text{fppf}$. Assume that $A$ and $C$ are representable by flat algebraic spaces. Why is $B$ representable by an algebraic space?

I've seen this statement several times but never seen a proof. I also wonder whether this result has an analogue for the étale topology.

Answer (score 7):

The main fact here is that, since $B$ fits into this short exact sequence, we have that $B$ is an $A$-torsor over $C$. In particular, fppf-locally on $C$, $B$ is a product of $A$ and $C$. But being an algebraic space is a local condition [Stacks Project, [Tag 04SK](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04SK)], and we win.

If you have a similar short exact sequence of étale sheaves, then [Stacks Project, [Tag 076L](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/076LL)] implies that $A$ and $C$ are also "fppf-algebraic spaces". The same idea as before also works here.